# Using a variable for a property name

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, constants

When I try this code, I cannot give a const to "option_code" in an object.

```
const option_code = "option1211";
const product_code = "3344";
const size_code = "44"

var product_data = {
    option_code: size_code,
    quantity: "1",
    product_id: product_code,
}
```

I want a result like this (option code needs to change) =>

```
{ option1211:'44', quantity:'1', product_id:'3344' }
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: There is no JSON in this question. Please don't abuse the name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close, you just need to add square brackets around the key name:

```
var product_data = {
    [option_code]: size_code,
    quantity: "1",
    product_id: product_code,
}
```

Otherwise, you can do the following:

```
var product_data = {
    quantity: "1",
    product_id: product_code,
}

product_data[option_code] = size_code;
```